# Weird typo in unanswered questions

Tags: bug

For unanswered questions, the following is displayed:

[image]

What should be at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I see:

[image]

No problem there. I don't know what could cause the problem on your side (maybe a browser problem?)

Comment: I'm using chrome, if that matters

Comment: @nirshahar, it looks OK for me too, I'm using chrome. I would check your extensions. E.g. some adblock extensions have an option "block social network buttons".

Comment: @Dmitry you are right. Seems my adblocker was blocking the buttons. I didn't specify that in the settings, so I assume that it is so by default. Thanks!